# Different behaviour of jdk8 vs jdk11 when using stream collect

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

## Intro

I do have a problem regarding the behaviour of jdk11 (and later) in terms of stream and the collect method.
I do want to get the values of a parameterized container streaming the resource and collect the values in the end with `.collect(Collectors.toSet())`.

## Problem description

When i compile my code with the `jdk8` it works perfectly fine. But as we also have to support `jdk11`, i ran the compilation and it fails because `Error:(136, 17) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.Set<org.bson.types.ObjectId>` (same applies for openJdk11)

## Use case

Imagine the following situation. I have a class which is basically a data container. This container can hold single values or lists of values.

Im some parts of my application, i do have lists of this container class (which can contain lists as values as well) and i do want to stream through the lists to get all the values in the containers as a flat list.

For this example i chose to use Lists of objectIds.

### Set up

```java
  // preparation
  List<ObjectId> innerObjects = new ArrayList<>();
  innerObjects.add(new ObjectId());
  innerObjects.add(new ObjectId());

  List<Diamond<Object>> diamonds = new ArrayList<>();
  diamonds.add(new Diamond<Object>().value(innerObjects));
```

### Container class

```java
  public static class Diamond<T> {
    private T value;

    public Diamond<T> value(T value) {
      this.value = value;
      return this;
    }

    public T getValue() {
      return this.value;
    }
  }
```

### Implemntation for collecting objectId value from the container. This is fone for the compiler of jdk8. But jdk11 fails here.

```java
    Set<ObjectId> objectIdSet = diamonds
        .stream()
        .filter(diamond -> diamond.getValue() instanceof List)
        .map(Diamond::getValue)
        .map(List.class::cast)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(ObjectId.class::cast)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

### Changing it to this implementation makes the jdk11 compiler happy.

```
    Stream<ObjectId> idStream = diamonds
        .stream()
        .filter(diamond -> diamond.getValue() instanceof List)
        .map(Diamond::getValue)
        .map(List.class::cast)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(ObjectId.class::cast);
    Set<ObjectId> objectIds = idStream.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

## Question

But i do not get why this is wrong.

`<deleted as of to be inacurate>`

*EDIT*:
I changed the set up code to reflect my current issue a bit more.

Anyone an idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand oyur last paragraph. You say that in your real code you use `Diamond<Object>` but you used a different type here. Do *both* these cases raise that exception or only your `Diamond<Object>` version fails?

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question, but perhaps you should consider always holding a collection of values (`ObjectId`s). Yes, probably mostly the collection would be a `Collections.singletonList(value)`, but that's fine. A collection of a single item is still a good collection.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta yes, my real code uses `Diamond<Object>`. I tried with the more explicit one, but both are failing.
I gonna adjust my question to be more precise.

Comment: Though I've failed to reproduce the compiler issue in Java-12, yet I am curious why do you tend to use  `List<Diamond<Object>> diamonds = new ArrayList<>();
  diamonds.add(new Diamond<Object>().value(innerObjects));`?

Answer (score 4):

This could be related to [JDK-8199234 Code compiles in java8 but not in java9 : "incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted ..."](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8199234) which was resolved as "Not an Issue" and affects Java 9+.

The root cause is that in your example `map(List.class::cast)` performs a cast to a raw type `List` messing up the information about generics. You are trying to rectify this later with `map(ObjectId.class::cast)` but it's not a good idea.  Streams are heavily based on the generics and you should avoid manual casts and let the compiler infer the types.

Your code can be simplified to below, which works on Java 11:

```
Set<ObjectId> objectIdSet = diamonds.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull) // potentially redundant but instanceof was doing it
        .map(Diamond::getValue)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: While this is all true, I think the question is *why did the compiler give an error* ? Or at least, it would be interesting to answer this question..

Comment: @YassinHajaj thats true. Also my problem is, that, as i wrote but maybe not present enought, my container is typed as `Diamond<Object>` which makes the `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` not compiling.

Comment: @MaVo your example is not using `Diamond<Object>` but `Diamond<List<ObjectId>>`.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki i adjusted the question to be more precise.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki i struggle to get the the answer given in the openJDK issue you mentioned to work in my code.

As is said, the answer you given first cannot be used in my scenario, cause i do have `Diamond<Object>` in use. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Just to be more detailed, `.map(List.class::cast)` gives you a `Stream<List>`, then `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` gives you a `Stream`, then `.map(ObjectId.class::cast)` on a raw `Stream` is like `map(Function)`, still yielding a raw `Stream` and `collect` on a raw `Stream` returns `Object`, the return type after type erasure. Replace `.map(List.class::cast)` with `.map(obj -> (List<?>)obj)`, to avoid raw types.